# Import local GeoJSON file into Leaflet

Tags: leaflet, javascript, geojson

I just used a leaflet. From [the geoJSON demo page](https://leafletjs.com/examples/choropleth/) I saw if you want to include data you have to use

```
<script src="data/us-states.geojson"></script>
```

and if you open the files looks like

```
var ustates = {
"type": "FeatureCollection",
......
[]
};
```

and if you want to call them use

```
var data = [ustates] ;
```

Is there another way to call the data?
The geojson file that I have has no initial variable and looks like this:

```
{
"type": "FeatureCollection",
......
[]
}
```

I have lots of data and I have to open 1 by 1 to add variable on geojson data so I mean can I just call the data like

```
var ustates = <?php include "data/us-states.geojson"; ?>
var data = [ustates];
```

Comment: Please, update the link.

Comment: https://leafletjs.com/examples/choropleth/

Answer (score 7):

We use this function in [our project](https://github.com/WeAreFairphone/fprsmap/blob/482b20cc127f978f31db4eac753a1de4842e2676/js/main.js#L5) (credits go to [Roberto MF](https://github.com/Roboe)):

```js
function fetchJSON(url) {
  return fetch(url)
    .then(function(response) {
      return response.json();
    });
}
```

It uses the [Fetch API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API) to download the file. You can simply use your path `data/us-states.geojson` as `url`. Example with your data:

```
var data = fetchJSON('data/us-states.geojson')
            .then(function(data) { return data })
```

---

Be aware that this doesn't work in Internet Explorer by default, but you can polyfill it by adding these lines to your HTML-`<head>`:

```
<script src="https://bowercdn.net/c/es6-promise-3.2.2/es6-promise.min.js" integrity="sha384-GF7IR8yT5028AbfHnSJSxX0Y1D+sicFNHXDyV1Hzcf4EISXdjP8uW0Q/0yFIHpTD" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://bowercdn.net/c/fetch-1.0.0/fetch.js" integrity="sha384-j9GCh0V617Ks+uEOZnAhwzTOWu5lPIlPW3QYRSfEwXd+x7VqP1XHNLgj3AIX7Mo0" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Comment: I just saw that I had made a mistake. I added a second line to the Javascript (`fetchJSON(...)` returns a Promise so you have to wait for it with `.then()`) and another Polyfill.

Answer (score 5):

I used JQuery to read a GeoJSON file. First need to add JQUery to the page, then I define the layer, add the data to the layer, and finally the map.

```
 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

var url = 'BaseBallFinal.json'; 
 //var bbTeam = L.geoJSON(null, {onEachFeature: forEachFeature, style: style});
  var bbTeam = L.geoJSON(null, {
        onEachFeature: forEachFeature, 
        pointToLayer: function (feature, latlng) {
            return L.circleMarker(latlng, geojsonMarkerOptions);
        }
  });

// Get GeoJSON data and create features.
$.getJSON(url, function(data) {
        bbTeam.addData(data);
});

bbTeam.addTo(map);
```

Here is my working example: http://www.gistechsolutions.com/leaflet/DEMO/Simple/indexMap1.html

And others:
http://www.gistechsolutions.com/leaflet/DEMO/

Comment: There is a typo in your working example, the code line: `var osm=...contributors'});` You may forget calling the `addTo` function.

Answer (score 3):

Very similar to the previous answer we use XHR to get the file and load the data into Leaflet.

```
const xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open('GET', 'data/us-states.geojson');
xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
xhr.responseType = 'json';
xhr.onload = function() {
    if (xhr.status !== 200) return
    L.geoJSON(xhr.response).addTo(map);
};
xhr.send();
```

Comment: let me test your code