# Loading GeoJSON file into map in Leaflet

Tags: leaflet, javascript, json

I put my GeoJSON file on my desktop, I don't know why my file can't load to the map.

My code:

```
    <html lang="en-US" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head profile="http://gmpg.org/xfn/11">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.5.1/dist/leaflet.css"
          integrity="sha512-xwE/Az9zrjBIphAcBb3F6JVqxf46+CDLwfLMHloNu6KEQCAWi6HcDUbeOfBIptF7tcCzusKFjFw2yuvEpDL9wQ=="
          crossorigin="" />
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.5.1/dist/leaflet.js"
            integrity="sha512-GffPMF3RvMeYyc1LWMHtK8EbPv0iNZ8/oTtHPx9/cc2ILxQ+u905qIwdpULaqDkyBKgOaB57QTMg7ztg8Jm2Og=="
            crossorigin=""></script>
    <!-- <script src="http://cdn.leafletjs.com/leaflet-0.7.3/leaflet.js"></script> -->
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.1.min.js"></script>


    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://leaflet.github.io/Leaflet.markercluster/dist/MarkerCluster.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://leaflet.github.io/Leaflet.markercluster/dist/MarkerCluster.Default.css" />
    <script src="https://leaflet.github.io/Leaflet.markercluster/dist/leaflet.markercluster-src.js"></script>


</head>

<body>
    <div id="map" style="height: 100%; border: 1px solid #AAA;"></div>
    <script>

        var osmUrl = 'https://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png',
            osmAttrib = '&copy; <a href="https://www.openstreetmap.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors',
            osm = L.tileLayer(osmUrl, { maxZoom: 20, attribution: osmAttrib });
        var map = L.map('map').setView([24.151687694799833, 120.64116954803465], 15).addLayer(osm);
        var markers = L.markerClusterGroup({ chunkedLoading: true });

        L.control.scale().addTo(map);


        fetch("TaichungRange.json")
            .then(response => response.json())
            .then(json => {
                kaoDist = L.geoJSON(json).bindPopup(function (layer) {
                    return layer.feature.properties.T_Name;
                }).addTo(map);
                map.fitBounds(kaoDist.getBounds());
            });

    </script>

</body>

</html>
```

It's my GeoJSON file (one of part):

```
{
  "type": "FeatureCollection",
  "features": [

    {
      "type": "Feature",
      "properties": {
        "OBJECTID": "302",
        "T_UID": "302",
        "Area": "927614.89822",
        "Town_ID": "6600100",
        "T_Name": "中區",
        "Add_Date": "2010\/12\/25",
        "Add_Accept": "",
        "Remark": "",
        "County_ID": "66",
        "C_Name": "臺中市",
        "_id": 19260614
      },
      "geometry": {
        "type": "Polygon",
        "coordinates": [
          [
            [ 120.679275089, 24.148159598 ],
            [ 120.680746339, 24.14693056 ],
            [ 120.681035742, 24.146691519 ],
            [ 120.681119318, 24.146684118 ],
            [ 120.681198137, 24.146687153 ],
            [ 120.6812498, 24.146689458 ],
            [ 120.681269462, 24.146690335 ],
            [ 120.681367571, 24.14666311 ],
            [ 120.681399751, 24.146635132 ],
            [ 120.681588083, 24.146471391 ],
            [ 120.681711827, 24.146364362 ],
            [ 120.681808943, 24.146294624 ],
            [ 120.68186855, 24.146224482 ],
            [ 120.681944231, 24.146160468 ],
            [ 120.681971512, 24.146137392 ],
            [ 120.68216784, 24.145980637 ],
            [ 120.682190007, 24.145966408 ],
            [ 120.682193164, 24.145941059 ],
            [ 120.68207943, 24.145674377 ],
            [ 120.681910802, 24.145305332 ],
            [ 120.681852215, 24.145205346 ],
            [ 120.681766169, 24.145107072 ],
            [ 120.681647289, 24.14488761 ],
            [ 120.681677529, 24.144737597 ],
            [ 120.681720599, 24.144655132 ],
            [ 120.681786683, 24.144541193 ],
            [ 120.681871331, 24.144472855 ],
            [ 120.682097159, 24.144294834 ],
            [ 120.682864052, 24.14365601 ],
            [ 120.683105, 24.143455298 ],
            [ 120.683632391, 24.142961913 ],
            [ 120.684324817, 24.142314127 ],
            [ 120.684548035, 24.142526109 ],
            [ 120.6850456, 24.142998449 ],
            [ 120.685300003, 24.143236931 ],
            [ 120.685426161, 24.143282059 ],
            [ 120.685566204, 24.143278952 ],
            [ 120.685644985, 24.143275693 ],
            [ 120.685766267, 24.14327484 ],
            [ 120.685767128, 24.143171096 ],
            [ 120.685771504, 24.14264364 ],
            [ 120.685782653, 24.141299902 ],
            [ 120.685792532, 24.140109133 ],
            [ 120.686002588, 24.140106189 ],
            [ 120.686050935, 24.137994258 ],
            [ 120.686041452, 24.137978084 ],
            [ 120.685971293, 24.137858474 ],
            [ 120.685916471, 24.137789386 ],
            [ 120.685869176, 24.137712286 ],
            [ 120.685794971, 24.137567458 ],
            [ 120.685778394, 24.137535105 ],
            [ 120.685736153, 24.137438478 ],
            [ 120.685724555, 24.137366002 ],
            [ 120.685674704, 24.137054524 ],
            [ 120.685666244, 24.136948791 ],
            [ 120.685632759, 24.136849887 ],
            [ 120.685549137, 24.136797977 ],
            [ 120.685244464, 24.136657042 ],
            [ 120.684009465, 24.136115106 ],
            [ 120.683401085, 24.135937811 ],
            [ 120.683123845, 24.135877651 ],
            [ 120.682466355, 24.13555262 ],
            [ 120.682409143, 24.135528204 ],
            [ 120.682235267, 24.13587901 ],
            [ 120.682167483, 24.135973451 ],
            [ 120.681155456, 24.136868921 ],
            [ 120.680824166, 24.13716205 ],
            [ 120.680370871, 24.137548549 ],
            [ 120.6791183, 24.138616525 ],
            [ 120.678731256, 24.138946524 ],
            [ 120.678384256, 24.139242378 ],
            [ 120.677814537, 24.139734567 ],
            [ 120.677238951, 24.140231818 ],
            [ 120.676765947, 24.140640445 ],
            [ 120.675763237, 24.141506669 ],
            [ 120.675497696, 24.141736062 ],
            [ 120.674715203, 24.142425815 ],
            [ 120.674677036, 24.142459457 ],
            [ 120.673558029, 24.143445817 ],
            [ 120.673834803, 24.143697505 ],
            [ 120.67480668, 24.14463683 ],
            [ 120.67490739, 24.144721035 ],
            [ 120.674960937, 24.144765952 ],
            [ 120.675003347, 24.144815686 ],
            [ 120.675016833, 24.144857945 ],
            [ 120.675026409, 24.144893387 ],
            [ 120.675027561, 24.144942771 ],
            [ 120.675039406, 24.145021847 ],
            [ 120.675030441, 24.145119715 ],
            [ 120.675029229, 24.145174909 ],
            [ 120.675019647, 24.145246356 ],
            [ 120.67504427, 24.145283797 ],
            [ 120.675091301, 24.145317352 ],
            [ 120.675143302, 24.145349643 ],
            [ 120.675181578, 24.145329354 ],
            [ 120.675313558, 24.145307207 ],
            [ 120.675533571, 24.145254582 ],
            [ 120.675579825, 24.145254816 ],
            [ 120.675621323, 24.145265486 ],
            [ 120.675655378, 24.145278606 ],
            [ 120.675690817, 24.145297445 ],
            [ 120.675746042, 24.145360713 ],
            [ 120.675969729, 24.145574322 ],
            [ 120.675988948, 24.145592676 ],
            [ 120.677156947, 24.14673958 ],
            [ 120.677301992, 24.146902216 ],
            [ 120.677379049, 24.146990334 ],
            [ 120.677459774, 24.147074937 ],
            [ 120.677539533, 24.147118184 ],
            [ 120.67762271, 24.147098123 ],
            [ 120.677627785, 24.147096899 ],
            [ 120.677675232, 24.147094814 ],
            [ 120.677705528, 24.147053984 ],
            [ 120.677718764, 24.147031882 ],
            [ 120.67775454, 24.147011641 ],
            [ 120.677777271, 24.147021531 ],
            [ 120.677848996, 24.147041953 ],
            [ 120.677919337, 24.147056648 ],
            [ 120.677959132, 24.147047811 ],
            [ 120.678015813, 24.146959344 ],
            [ 120.678070572, 24.146949066 ],
            [ 120.678114596, 24.146960834 ],
            [ 120.678183218, 24.147008898 ],
            [ 120.678219205, 24.147104738 ],
            [ 120.678368052, 24.147376481 ],
            [ 120.678421317, 24.147462779 ],
            [ 120.678418978, 24.147576598 ],
            [ 120.678458618, 24.147721782 ],
            [ 120.678541185, 24.147831626 ],
            [ 120.67863775, 24.147898673 ],
            [ 120.67872663, 24.14795783 ],
            [ 120.678763641, 24.147990433 ],
            [ 120.678847187, 24.148088766 ],
            [ 120.678947272, 24.148199423 ],
            [ 120.679053324, 24.148244449 ],
            [ 120.679114652, 24.14824782 ],
            [ 120.679208748, 24.148209183 ],
            [ 120.679275089, 24.148159598 ]
          ]
        ]
      }
    },
```

Comment: Possible duplicated https://gis.stackexchange.com/q/305646/49538

Comment: Are you running your map from web server or from your local file system?

Comment: @TomazicM Yes, but the file didn't load on the map. I validate the file is a json file.

Comment: Sorry, but answering yes doesn't help. Question is, where are you running you map (your html code above) from? Reply has to be explicit: server OR file system.

Comment: @TomazicM  I run the map on web server

Comment: What does your browser's error console tell you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you run your map from server and would like show your local GeoJSON file on map, you will have to upload your file. Usual method for this is using `FileReader()` object (see for example https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3582671/how-to-open-a-local-disk-file-with-javascript).

In your case I would recommend Leaflet plugin [Leaflet.FileLayer](https://github.com/makinacorpus/Leaflet.FileLayer), which can do exactly what you want: upload GeoJSON to your map. See example http://makinacorpus.github.io/Leaflet.FileLayer/